# How to insert value into certain column?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my `Instructor` table:

```
    ID  CHAR(5 BYTE)
    NAME    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
    DEPT_NAME   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   
    SALARY  NUMBER(8,2) 
    GENDER  CHAR(1 BYTE)
```

And currently I only have 1 registered instructor

```
1       Khaled  HR  16000   (null)
```

I want to add a gender for Khaled, I tried:

```
insert into instructor (gender) values('M');
```

but I get this error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
> insert into instructor (gender) values('M')
> Error report -
> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."INSTRUCTOR"."NAME")

Comment: because you need to UPDATE-record, not insert the new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  update for change existing record

```
update instructor
set gender = 'M'
where name ='Khaled'
```

or

```
update instructor
set gender = 'M'
where id ='1'
```